# Angular get query param and call service

Tags: angular, typescript, subscribe, query-string, angular-activatedroute

I've got a problem in my angular app. I have to call a service reading some params from url. It's not working because the service is fired before the subscription to have the params is finished. In my service file I have this:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.param1 = params['param1'];
      this.param2 = params['param2'];
    });
  }
```

and then the service:

```
getConfigs() {
    let configPath = baseUrl + this.param1 + "/" + this.param2;
    return this.http.get<any>(configPath);
  }
```

so, in my `AppComponent` I call the `getConfigs()` service but it's not working because the two params are undefined. How can I fix it? That's how I call the service in `AppComponent`

```
this.service.getConfigs().subscribe((configData) => {
      this.configParams = configData;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the query parameters from router, and use the `first()` operator to get only the first event and then use `switchMap()` to get the data with params option.

```
  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient,
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  getConfigs() {
    return this._route.queryParams.pipe(
      // rxjs operator skip empty object
      filter(params => !!Object.keys(params).length),
      // rxjs operator use only first event
      first(),
      // rxjs operator switch to another observable
      switchMap(params => this._http.get('host', { params })),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly if I use the first() operator it fires only the first request with undefined values

Comment: @End.Game where do you call the function?

Comment: In the constructor o the AppComponent

Answer (score 2):

You could use a RxJS higher order mapping operator like [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) to chain co-dependent observables. Try the following

```js
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

getConfigs() {
  return this.route.queryParams.pipe(
    switchMap(params => {
      let configPath = baseUrl + params['param1'] + "/" + params['param2'];
      return this.http.get<any>(configPath);
    })
  );
}
```

Although I'd say it's better to get the route params in the component instead of the service. So you could do something like the following

Service

```js
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getConfigs(param1: any, param2: any) {
  const configPath = baseUrl + param1 + '/' + param2;
  return this.http.get<any>(configPath);
}
```

Component

```
constructor(private someService: SomeService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.pipe(
    switchMap(params => this.someService.getConfigs(params['param1'], params['param2']))
  ).subscribe(
    ...
  );
}
```

Comment: I think that is the best answer but, I don't know why, the request is called 2 times. One with undefined params and the second one is correct. Of course if I check that params['param1'] is undefined the request not fires. Any idea?

Comment: I still have this weird problem. I don't know why it tries to fires 2 requests

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass values to the service.

```
this.service.getConfigs(this.param1, this.param2).subscribe((configData) => {
      this.configParams = configData;
});

getConfigs(param1, param2) {
    let configPath = baseUrl + param1 + "/" + param2;
    return this.http.get<any>(configPath);
  }
```